# Problema para submeter formulário a partir de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, formulário

Tenho um form e gostaria de submeter ele sem recarregar a pagina estou tentando isso com javascript, quando tento clicar no botao ele nao submete o formulario como pedi

```
<form  id="myForm" method='GET'>
```

";
  ?>

```
<script>
```

function SubmitFormData() {
    var codigopasta = $("#codigopasta").val();
    $.post("listadetexto.php", { codigopasta: codigopasta},
    function(data) {
  //Para o caso da página gravar_dados.php enviar alguma resposta depois de receber os dados
    });
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você faz o submit() pelo javascript, ele vai recarregar a página.

Uma forma fácil de fazer isso seria utilizando Jquery. Aqui tem um exemplo que você pode utilizar para alterar o seu formulário:

```js
function SubmitFormData() {
    var nome = $("#nome").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var telefone = $("#telefone").val();
    var sexo = $("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
    $.post("gravar_dados.php", { nome: nome, email: email, telefone: telefone, sexo: sexo },
    function(data) {
 //Para o caso da página gravar_dados.php enviar alguma resposta depois de receber os dados
    });
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>Enviar sem recarregar a página</title>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/submit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="myForm" method="post">
     Nome:    <input name="nome" id="nome" type="text" /><br />
     Email:   <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />
     Telefone:<input name="telefone" id="telefone" type="text" /><br />
     Sexo:  <input name="sexo" type="radio" value="masculino">Masculino
       <input name="sexo" type="radio" value="feminino">Feminino<br />

    <input type="button" id="submitFormData" onclick="SubmitFormData();" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   <br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Perceba que no exemplo o formulário não possui um botão do tipo submit

Comment: editei a pegunta para tentar fazer com o que propos mas não consegui observa na pergunta pf

Comment: Você precisa postar o HTML do seu formulário, ele não aparece na sua pergunta.